# How to define the MFP javascript adapter for the working poster REST call?

Tags: javascript, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I want to write a MFP adapter (v8) which communicate with a Web-Server.
The server waits for a parameter image containing image information.
The mobile client implementation is in ionic cordova.

First I did a check in the Poster which is the right request to send, but I am not able to find the right configuration/implementation/call for the adapter.

What I am doing wrong?

**1) This is the working copied poster call**

```
POST /GetImageKeywords HTTP/1.1
Host: XXXXXXX.mybluemix.net:443
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: a98cac04-fe12-3e0f-2884-250bb5ff39ae
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

image=data%3..................
```

**2) And this is the not working MFP adapter implementation:**

```
function getTagsForPicture(urlimage) {
 var input = {
    method : 'post',
    returnedContentType : 'xml',
    path : 'GetImageKeywords',
  parameters: {'image': urlimage },
  headers: {"Accept":"application\/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "Content-Type":"application\/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
 };
 return MPF.Server.invokeHttp(input);
}
```

**3) This is the mobile client side adapter call:**

```
var getTagsRequest = new WLResourceRequest(
              "/adapters/UploadPic/getTagsForPicture",
              WLResourceRequest.POST);

              getTagsRequest.setQueryParameter("params", "['image']" );
              getTagsRequest.send().then(
                  getTagsSuccess,
                  getTagsFailure
              );

           function getTagsSuccess (result){
                console.log('Success, getTags is : ', result);
                q.resolve(result);
                WL.SimpleDialog.show(
                      "Got Tags", "You can continue using the application",
                      [{text: "OK, thanks", handler: function() {WL.Logger.debug("Got Tags"); }
                      }]
                );             
           };

           function getTagsFailure (result){
                console.log('Failure, getTags is : ', result);
                q.reject(result);
                WL.SimpleDialog.show(
                        "Got NO Tags", "Try it again later.",
                              [{text: "OK, thanks", handler: function() {WL.Logger.debug("Got NO Tags"); }
                              }]
           ); 
           }
           console.log("Tags*** ", q);
           return q.promise;
```

**Loginformation in chrome**

```
{responseHeaders: Object, status: 500, responseText: "{"errors":["Unexpected error in server, see logs"],"isSuccessful":false,"warnings":[],"info":[]}", responseJSON: Object, invocationContext: null}
invocationContext:null
responseHeaders:Object
responseJSON:Object
responseText
:"{"errors":["Unexpected error in server, see logs"],"isSuccessful":false,"warnings":[],"info":[]}"
status:500
```

**Log on the MFP Dev Server:**

```
Error   FWLST0904E: Exception was thrown while invoking procedure: getTagsForPicture in adapter: UploadPic
Date    Wednesday, Jun 1, 2016, 9:27 PM
Server  fe80:0:0:0:a65e:60ff:fedc:5a99%4
Security Level  Error
Source Class    com.ibm.mfp.server.js.adapter.internal.JavascriptManagerImpl
Source Method Name  
Logger Name com.ibm.mfp.server.js.adapter.internal.JavascriptManagerImpl
Thread ID   1743
Message FWLST0904E: Exception was thrown while invoking procedure: getTagsForPicture in adapter: UploadPic
```

**Config.xml information:**

```
<procedure name="getTagsForPicture" secured="false"/>
<procedure name="uploadVacationInformationComplete" secured="false"/>
<procedure name="unprotected" secured="false"/>
```

Comment: can you try adding `securityTest="wl_unprotected"` in your getTagsForPicture procedure? `<procedure name="getTagsForPicture" securityTest="wl_unprotected"/>`

Comment: Thanks, for paying attention and willing to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a spelling error **MPF** and I found the solution for the configuration:

Here is the working implementation of the javascript adapter:

```
function getTagsForPicture(urlimage) {
   var value = "image=" + urlimage;
   MFP.Logger.warn("Image input " + value.toString());
   var requestStructure = {
        method : 'post',
        returnedContentType : 'xml',
        path : 'GetImageKeywords',
      parameters: {'image': urlimage },
      headers: {"Accept":"application\/plain"}
     };
   MFP.Logger.warn("Preparing request structure " + JSON.stringify(requestStructure));
   return MFP.Server.invokeHttp(requestStructure);
 }
```

Inside the Client there was an error related to **("params", "['image']" )** the right one is **("params", [image] )**.

```
var getTagsRequest = new WLResourceRequest(
              "/adapters/UploadPic/getTagsForPicture",
              WLResourceRequest.POST);

              getTagsRequest.setQueryParameter("params", [image] );
              getTagsRequest.send().then(
                  getTagsSuccess,
                  getTagsFailure
              );

           function getTagsSuccess (result){
                console.log('Success, getTags is : ', result);
                q.resolve(result);
                WL.SimpleDialog.show(
                      "Got Tags", "You can continue using the application",
                      [{text: "OK, thanks", handler: function() {WL.Logger.debug("Got Tags"); }
                      }]
                );             
           };

           function getTagsFailure (result){
                console.log('Failure, getTags is : ', result);
                q.reject(result);
                WL.SimpleDialog.show(
                        "Got NO Tags", "Try it again later.",
                              [{text: "OK, thanks", handler: function() {WL.Logger.debug("Got NO Tags"); }
                              }]
           ); 
           }
```